# Rendering html in slim string, sinatra

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra, slim-lang

I need to render a string in slim to html while using sinatra .html_safe does not work in sinatra.

```
p = paper[3]
```

where paper[3] is

```
Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed
<br>  ipsum, earum, perspiciatis consequuntur atque sapiente at,
<br> 
<br> voluptatem corrupti consectetur velit illo quasi nulla corporis
<br> 
<br>  nam pariatur ut cupiditate amet est.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `==` instead `=` in Slim template to output strings without HTML escaping.

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Output_without_HTML_escaping___

In sample app.rb:

```
get '/' do
  @string = "<ul><li>Lorem</li><li>ipsum</li></ul>"
  slim :index
end
```

In Slim template:

```
html
  body

    div
      / will output escaped string 
      = @string

    div
      / will output unescaped HTML list
      == @string
```